# Gradle setup to pick different jar files release and debug build

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use different jar files debug and release build in my app. 
How can i configure gradle to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily specify dependencies for each build type, in the form of `<buildType>Compile`,  in your case:

```
dependencies {
    //other dependencies
    debugCompile files('libs/libA.jar')
    releaseCompile files('libs/libB.jar')
}
```

For more informations refer to the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-on-binary-packages).